# Error when calling classroom PHP API method: courses.courseWork.list

Tags: google-classroom

So I use the Google Classroom PHP API to integrate it with my project. When the user is requested to logging with the google account, I request the following scopes.

Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY,     Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ROSTERS_READONLY,           Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_PROFILE_EMAILS,           **Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS_READONLY,**
Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ANNOUNCEMENTS_READONLY

Interesting enough, the accessToken generated returns the following scopes:

Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY,     Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ROSTERS_READONLY,           Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_PROFILE_EMAILS,           **Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_STUDENT_SUBMISSIONS_STUDENTS_READONLY,**             Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ANNOUNCEMENTS_READONLY

The problem is that courses.courseWork.list specifically requires Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS_READONLY, as stated in the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list).

So as a result I'm getting an error:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":403,
      "message":"The caller does not have permission",
      "errors":[
         {
            "message":"The caller does not have permission",
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"forbidden"
         }
      ],
      "status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or this might be an API bug?

---

Adding further details on the code.
First the frontend request the Authorization URL, that one where the user will login and accept the scopes being requested. This is done with the following methods: Frontend > getAuthorizationURL > getGoogleAuthorizationURL.

```
public function getAuthorizationURL($parameters) {
    
    $classroomIntegration = new classroomIntegration();
    $asyncState = $classroomIntegration->generateGoogleAsyncState(classroomIntegration::$CLASSROOM_INTEGRATION, $parameters->userID);
    $resultUrl = googleLogin::getGoogleAuthorizationURL("callback.php", 
                                                        $asyncState, 
                                                       [Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY,
                                                        Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ROSTERS_READONLY,
                                                        Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_PROFILE_EMAILS,
                                                        Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS_READONLY,
                                                        Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ANNOUNCEMENTS_READONLY,
                                                        Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE]);
    
    
    $this->respond(TRUE, $resultUrl);
}
    
    
public static function getGoogleAuthorizationURL($callbackRelativePath, $asyncState, $scopes){

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $httpHost = constant("httpHost");

    $client->setAuthConfig("credentials.json");
    $client->setRedirectUri("http://" . $httpHost . $callbackRelativePath);

    $client->setApplicationName("Dummy App");
    $client->setPrompt("consent");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
    foreach($scopes as $scope){
        $client->addScope($scope);
    }

    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $client->setState($asyncState);

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    return filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
}
```

Than in the callback file I just get the access code, which contains the tokens and the scopes that were granted:

```
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "code");
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
```

So basically on the list of scopes that were granted, instead of getting the Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS_READONLY as requested I'm being granted the Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_STUDENT_SUBMISSIONS_STUDENTS_READONLY. Problem is that courses.courseWork.list requires the first one.

Comment: Where have you defined your scopes in your call? Can you share your PHP code?

Comment: Hi Rafa! I've just added further information. Hope this helps to clarify the situation.

Comment: Try removing your token file and reauthorising?

Comment: Hi Rafa! Yes, I did force a revoke and reauthorised but yet the problem persists :'(

Comment: Try and obtain a new set of credentials from GCP and use those - in case there's an issue with the curernt JSON file which requests different scopes to those that you need